# Edit position of an Android button created with a linearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to dynamically create buttons, and they will be of varying size and in varying positions.
I have the code to create a button of varying size, but I am stuck on changing the position.
I am using linearlayout and am trying to use setMargins to move the button around, but it seems to be changing the margin within the button. My code is as follows:

```
public void button(int a, int b) {

    newButton = new Button(this);
    newButton.setText("HELLO");

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); 

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = a;
    params.height = b;
    layout.requestLayout();

    layout.addView(newButton, layoutParams);

}
```

Here is my manifest for this bit:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="50sp"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand what a LinearLayout is and why you're using it? Every child of the layout snaps in place. If I have a LinearLayout that's vertical and it has 3 children they will be on top of each other. I can change their gravity so they are attracted to different margins but to "change" its position is impossible depending on what you mean by "change".

Check out the other layouts. You may want to use a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I didn't understand that until you pointed it out. Thank you for your reply I appreciate your help. I will look into relative layout

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you use button.setX(float x) and button.setY(float y)? You'll need to use RelativeLayout instead of the LinearLayout. It's more easy but it's only available since api 11...

Comment: I'm glad it has been useful! Please, set the answer as a correct